# NEC LaVie LM750/H LAPTOP won't boot and only shows black screen with blinking line on top left of screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb, bios

Im trying to boot my laptop from a USB Flashdrive (SanDisk Cruzer Switch) so I can perform a clean installation of windows 10 pro x64 but it only shows a blank black screen and a blinking white underscore or white line on the top left of the screen.

Here's the list of things I tried but still failed:

1. Used rufus latest version to burn my flash drive with windows 10.
2. Configured the boot order from BIOS. Made the flash drive to be the first boot priority.
3. Made the hard drive to be the first boot priority and the flash drive to be the second.
4. Made the hard drive the first boot priority, CD/DVD ROM to be the second and the flash drive to be the last.
5. Removed the hard drive from its laptop and connected the hard drive to another laptop using SATA USB cable in order to format it and removed some partitions. (Has 3 current partitions)
6. Used Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool to burn windows 10 x64 ISO image file into my flash drive.
7. Turned on my laptop and reached the black screen with the sign "Reboot and select proper boot device" and inserted my flash drive and press entered once.
8. Tried all the USB Ports
9. Converted the flash drive from NTFS format to FAT32
10. Disabled and Enabled the USB Legacy Support
11. Inserted another working hard drive (With windows 10 OS installed)
12. Removed the laptop's internal hard drive and used it on another laptop to install Windows 10 OS.

**Note: My BIOS version is Aptio Setup Utility 2.11.1210. My flash drive is formatted on NTFS. ISO used is not corrupted.**

Laptop Specs:

- 8 GB RAM
- Intel i7 Processor with x64 architecture

For further information you can ask on comment.

Comment: Two suggestions, not how to solve the current issue but how to do it differently. If you can still boot the old Windows 10 on the hard drive use the Windows 10 Refresh tool to make a clean install from within (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh). If not create a Windows 10 Bootable USB using the media creation tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I wiped out all the contents of the hard drive using disk management. I tried the media creation tool but still won't work..